# How can I add a hover state on an SVG file if it's imported as an image in HTML?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, svg

This is what my code looks like:

```
<div class="social-links mt-1 mb-3">
  <p>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/junomattress">
      <span class="markdown-icon">
        <img src="/wp-content/themes/dawn-child/assets/images/icon-facebook.svg">
      </span>
    </a>
  </p>

  <p>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/sleepdouglas">
      <span class="markdown-icon">
        <img src="/wp-content/themes/dawn-child/assets/images/icon-twitter.svg">
      </span>
    </a>
  </p>

  <p>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/sleepdouglas/">
      <span class="markdown-icon">
        <img src="/wp-content/themes/dawn-child/assets/images/icon-instagram.svg">
      </span>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

How can I add a hover state on the SVG, which is imported in the HTML as an image?

Comment: What kind of hover state are you talking about? If you want to change the fill of paths and etc inside the svg, then you’re out of luck: that requires the svg to be embedded inline.

Comment: yeah, I want to change the fill of the paths. SO there's no work around to do change the fill on hover if it's not embedded?

Comment: Nope, no way around it.

Answer (score -1):

Using HTML attribute `class` add class to the `img` tag for the svg elements you are targeting.

For example:

```
<img class="hvr" src="/wp-content/themes/dawn-child/assets/images/icon-twitter.svg">
```

Then in CSS you target that class with `:hover` selector:

```css
.hvr:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5); //just an example
}
```

Comment: I did try to do that but if I want to change the fill color of the svg, it doesn't work. Here's a codepen example: https://codepen.io/jagriti_130501/pen/jOxLYEz. If you add a random svg, on hover the color will not get changed to green. It does transform, yes and everything else works but any css which is meant for the svg does not work unless I'm approaching it in an incorrect way.

Comment: Since you are using svg element inside an `img` tag, you can't use the `fill` css property. If you don't want to use inline svg, you could try to achieve the fill color change using `filter` css property and playing with various values of saturation, hue, grayscale, etc.